# How to reshape matrix into row-major order for MKL DSS?

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I would like to use MKL to solve a sparse linear system. I chose the [DSS (Direct Sparse Solver)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/470302) interface, which implements the following steps:

```
//(1).define the non-zero structure of the matrix
dss_define_structure(handle, sym, rowIndex, nRows, nCols, columns, nNonZeros);
//(2).reorder the matrix
dss_reorder(handle, opt, 0);
//(3).factor the matrix
dss_factor_real(handle, type, values);
//(4).get the solution vector
dss_solve_real(handle, opt, rhs, nRhs, solValues);
//(5).deallocate solver storage
dss_delete(handle, opt);
```

According to my test, the DSS uses a column-major ordering. That means

```
//column = 3
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
```

is equivalent to

```
{{1,  6,  11},
 {2,  7,  12},
 {3,  8,  13},
 {4,  9,  14}
 {5, 10,  15}}
```

For instance, there is a sparase linear system $\mathbf A_{5\times 5}\mathbf X_{5\times 3}=\mathbf B_{5\times 3}$

where $\mathbf A$ is symmetric sparse array

[image]

```
//A stored with CSR3 format
rowIndex = { 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
columns = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
values = { 9, 1.5, 6, .75, 3, 0.5, 12, .625, 16 };
//B
rhs[5*3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
//X
solValues[15]
```

By calling the above DSS interface, the `solValues` is

```
{-326.333, 983, 163.417, 398, 61.5, 
 -844.667, 2548, 423, 1028, 159, 
-1363, 4113, 682.583, 1658, 256.5}
```

Namely

$$
\mathbf X_{5\times 3}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -326.333 & -844.667 & -1363 \\
 983 & 2548 & 4113 \\
 163.417 & 423 & 682.583 \\
 398 & 1028 & 1658 \\
 61.5 & 159 & 256.5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In my application, the matrix is row-major. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: The example you show is a dense matrix. The DSS (obviously) deals with the sparse matrix format (shown here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/599832#68B04CF4-CC22-4441-9EE9-F2974482A668). How are you storing the *sparse* matrix in your software?

Comment: @BillGreene In my application, I also stores the sparse matrix with CSR3 format via zero-based indexing.

Comment: @BillGreene In addition, for a linear system $\mathbf A_{n \times n}\mathbf X_{n \times c}=\mathbf B_{n \times c}$ , the storing of $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf B $ are in row-major ordering

Comment: According to the DSS documentation page I referenced, it requires CSR format. So you should be all set.